# How do I get the highest property from a laravel eloquent object

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-5.7

consider the following Model Object:

```
App\Modules\CharacterSheets\Models\CharacterSheet {#826
  ...
  #attributes: array:39 [
    "id" => 1
    "user_id" => 1
    "race_id" => 1
    "class_id" => null
    "strength" => 35
    "dexterity" => 35
    "agility" => 55
    "intelligence" => 30
    "health" => 120
    "haste" => 0
    "precision" => 0
    "dodge" => 0
    "crit" => 0
    "steal_health" => 5
    "gold" => 0
    "deffense" => 7
    "damage" => 10
    "cast_damage" => 10
    "antique_damage" => 0
    "heal_for" => 10
    "level" => 1
    "train_exp" => 0
    "level_exp" => 200
    "location" => "0, 0"
    "next_level_exp" => 1000
    "next_train_level_exp" => 300
    "max_level" => 500
    "armor_class" => 17
    "block_bonus" => 3
    "hit_bonus" => 2
    "has_to_train" => 0
    "primary_attack_stat" => "health"
    "primary_attack_bonus" => "2.00"
    "penalty_stat" => null
    "penalty" => null
    "damage_subtraction" => null
    "chance_to_attack_twice" => null
    "created_at" => "2019-02-16 01:26:04"
    "updated_at" => "2019-02-16 01:56:42"
  ]
  ...
}
```

What I would like to do, **dynamically**, is check which of the following stats are the highest: `strength`, `dexterity`, `agility`, `intelligence`, `health`

I want to keep the object as is, but return the property name as a string

So for example with the above object, I should have function that returns `health`.

**Again this has to be dynamic**.

I didn't see any laravel collection methods that would do this, so I am asking here as I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract property from model and find max value key.

```
function getHighestProperty(Model $model, array $keys): string
{
    $filter = array_flip($keys);
    $array = collect($model->toArray());
    return $array->intersectByKeys($filter)->sort()->flip()->last();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done like this though I have not tried it:

First we will make an array of attributes that we want.

```
$array = [
    'strength', 'dexterity', 'agility', 'intelligence', 'health',
];
```

Next, create an result collection to store the sheet data that are available in the above `$array`.

```
$result = collect();
```

Loop the sheet and check whether the key exists in the above array. If it exists, we shall put it in the `$result` collection.

```
foreach ($characterSheet as $key => $sheetAttribute) {
    if (in_array($key, $array)) {
        $result->put($key, $sheetAttribute);
    }
}
```

Then we can sort the `$result` collection using [sort](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sort) method to give us the minimum value along with its key. Then you can [flip](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-flip) it, so as to get the key asscociated with that value and return the [last](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-last) element, because you want the maximum.

```
$result->sort()->flip()->last();
```

And then you can simply `dd($result)` and cross verify whether this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First, make the logic. In this case, we'll use [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections):

```php
// CharacterSheet.php

public function highestProperty()
{
    // temporal variable
    $temp = collect();

    // populating the temporal variable
    collect(['strength', 'dexterity', 'agility', 'intelligence', 'health'])
        ->each(function ($property) use ($temp) {
            return $temp->put($property, $this->$property);
        });

    // searching the property of the highest value
    return $temp->search(
        // getting the highest value
        $temp->reduce(function ($highest, $value) {
            return ($highest < $value) ? $value : $highest;
        })
    );
}
```

Then, create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators), so you could do `$characterSheet->highest_property`:

```php
// CharacterSheet.php

public function getHighestPropertyAttribute()
{
    return $this->highestProperty();
}
```

You can even [append](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) this value to every `CharacterSheet` instance adding the value to the `$appends` model config:

```php
// CharacterSheet.php

$appends = ['highest_property'];
```

Now, whenever you get an instance of the `CharacterSheet`, you can use it like any other attribute:

```php
$characterSheet = CharacterSheet::first();

dd($characterSheet->highest_property);

// this could output, if the case: "dexterity"
```